# Azure pipeline with VS Test step failing to complete

Tags: azure, visual-studio, selenium, azure-devops, specflow

I have a azure pipeline which fails now that I have added a Visual Studio step. Prior to this the pipeline would complete fine using Ubuntu-20.04 as the agent. Now I want to run the selenium tests as part of the pipeline ->

[image]

I then added the VS steps to run Selenium tests before deploying the code thus ->

[image]

I set the agent to vs2017-win2016 but everytime I run I get this error ->

[image]

```
    Starting: Spice buildAndPush
==============================================================================
Task         : Docker
Description  : Build or push Docker images, login or logout, start or stop containers, or run a Docker command
Version      : 2.192.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azpipes-docker-tsg
==============================================================================
"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
3.1: Pulling from dotnet/aspnet
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.14393 in the manifest list entries
"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" inspect mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
Error: No such object: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
[]
"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" build -f D:\a\1\s\spicetheworld\Dockerfile --label com.azure.dev.image.system.teamfoundationcollectionuri=https://dev.azure.com/kevsbox/ --label com.azure.dev.image.system.teamproject=spicetheworld --label com.azure.dev.image.build.repository.name=spicetheworld --label com.azure.dev.image.build.sourceversion=fa0c5f9183c04296b6c1a33acbcc312cc2ffae50 --label com.azure.dev.image.build.repository.uri=https://kevsbox@dev.azure.com/kevsbox/spicetheworld/_git/spicetheworld --label com.azure.dev.image.build.sourcebranchname=development --label com.azure.dev.image.build.definitionname=SpiceThis --label com.azure.dev.image.build.buildnumber=20211022.8 --label com.azure.dev.image.build.builduri=vstfs:///Build/Build/201 --label image.base.ref.name=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 -t ***/spicedevrepository:latest D:\a\1\s\spicetheworld
Sending build context to Docker daemon   12.9MB

Step 1/27 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
3.1: Pulling from dotnet/aspnet
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.14393 in the manifest list entries
##[error]The process 'C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Spice buildAndPush
```

So I then changed the agent to windows-2019 and ran it again. This time no errors flagged ->

[image]
But my test website is no longer working ->
[image]

This is then fixed by running the Ubuntu pipeline. I am using VS 2019, Selenium 4.0.0, NUnit 3.13.3, Specflow 3.9.22

This is the Docker file used in the final step

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["spicetheworld.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "spicetheworld.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "spicetheworld.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "spicetheworld.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "spicetheworld.dll"]
```

So anyone got any ideas on where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your restrictions, you can try to separate the Visual Studio tests into its own job within the pipeline so that you can run those on a windows-server-2019 agent, while still building the app using the Ubuntu agent in a separate job. One job running your original build steps on Ubuntu (what was working originally), then a second job to run the Visual Studio tasks (windows-server-2019).